# Why Date adds 1 month automatically?

Tags: java, date, calendar

Basically, I want my result is what I expected that print 2012-10-23. However, It is very wired. 
Here is my codes:

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2012, 10, 22);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
Date startDate = new Date();

startDate = cal.getTime();

String date = ft.format(startDate).toString();
System.out.println(date);
```

I want to print 2012-10-23, but the result is 2012-11-23.

Can someone tell me why it adds 1 month automatically?  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the inconsistency hell of Java Date and Calendar API.

Comment: Avoid use of "magic" numbers. Use the Calendar constants instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Calendar` class months starts from 0, not from 1, so when setting month as 10 you're not setting October but November.

Change your code to

```
cal.set(2012, 9, 22);
```

Or even better

```
cal.set(2012, Calendar.OCTOBER, 22);
```

More info:

- [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)